# GRE combinations problem involving cards and repetition.

Tags: combinatorics

A set of cards is numbered 1 through 5.

Which of the two quantities is larger?

**Quantity A**

The number of ways to pick 3 of the 5 cards such that card number 1 is included

**Quantity B**

The number of ways to pick 3 of the 5 cards such that card number 1 is excluded

So it seems like the number of ways to pick 3 of the 5 cards such that number 1 is included is:

$\frac{5!}{3!2!}$ =  10

But what's the intuition? That formula seems to mean

> "the number of 5 card combinations such of 3 of them meet some
>   criteria and 2 do not".

Why does the formula also mean "the number of 3 card combinations that include a 1"?

Answer (score 2):

The number of ways to pick $3$ of the $5$ cards such that card number $1$ is $\color\green{\text{included}}$:

$\color\green{\text{Take}}$ card number $1$ and then choose $\color\red{2}$ out of the remaining $4$ cards: $\dbinom{4}{\color\red{2}}=6$.

---

The number of ways to pick $3$ of the $5$ cards such that card number $1$ is $\color\green{\text{excluded}}$:

$\color\green{\text{Burn}}$ card number $1$ and then choose $\color\red{3}$ out of the remaining $4$ cards: $\dbinom{4}{\color\red{3}}=4$.

Answer (score 1):

No, the number of ways to pick 3 and include 1 is
$$\binom{1}{1}\times\binom{4}{2} = 1\cdot 6 = 6.$$
In other words, there is one way to choose the card labeled 1. Then you are free to choose two cards from the remaining 4. there are six ways to do that.

The number of ways to pick 3 and exculde 1 is
$$\binom{1}{0}\times\binom{4}{3} = 1\cdot 4 = 4.$$
In other words, there is one way to exclude (not pick) the card labeled 1. Then you are free to choose 3 of the remaining 4 cards. There are four ways to do that.

The answer you have
$$\binom{5}{3} = 10$$
does not guarantee inclusion or exclusion of the card labeled 1.
Meaning, it counts the case $\{1,2,3\}$, but it also counts the case $\{3,4,5\}$. That is, you have counted all the ways to choose 3 cards from the 5: all subsets of size 3 from the 5 cards.